Symmetrical Endomorphisms diagonalized by Orthogonal Matrices
I'd like to know where to find, or if you can show me a proof generalized to all non-singular scalar products, of the following statement (a ST corollary):
"Let A be the matrix associated with $f$, $f$ being a symmetrical endomorphism on $V$ w.r.t. the standard product. Then it exists $O$ such that:
\begin{equation}
O^{-1} A O = ^{\top}OAO = D \quad  \text{(where D is diagonal)}
\end{equation}
"
ì
In a lot of exercises it is implied that if a passage-of-basis is acted upon a symmetrical matrix $A$, for a generic starting base $B$, since due to ST you can always find an orthonormal base $C$ of eigenvectors w.r.t. to $A$ as long as the product is non-singular, then $O = [I]^B_C$ (passage-of-basis matrix from $B$ to $C$) has to be orthogonal.
Is it truly like this or have I gotten it wrong?
